# histogram of raster coordinates in R

Tags: raster, r

I'm trying to generate an histogram of the y coordinates where raster values are 1. Mysteriously the following, different rasters, give me the same histogram. What could I be doing wrong?

here are the rasters:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8d47f7869kcrfvo/AACpgCfe1-Bt7xD6j1rAUebda?dl=0

```
require(raster)
raster1=raster("raster1.grd")
raster2=raster("raster2.grd")
plot(raster1)
plot(raster2)

one=xyFromCell(raster1,which(values(raster1)==1))[,2] 
two=xyFromCell(raster2,which(values(raster2)==1))[,2] 

hist(one, xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,.3),col="red",freq=F,main="",xlab="Latitude")
hist(two,freq=F,col="green",add=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The histograms are different.

```
head(table(one))
##one
##31 32 33 34 35 36 
## 1  2  1  2  2  2

head(table(two))
##two
##18 19 22 23 24 25 
## 2  1  3  4  2  5 


stem(one, 0.5)

#  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

#  3 | 1223445566778888999
#  4 | 00012223333344444444455555555566666667777777778888888888899999999999
#  5 | 00000000000000111111111111111111111222222222222222222222223333333333+106
#  6 | 00000000000011111111111111222222222222223333333333333344444444445555+53
#  7 | 00000000000000011111111111111112222222222222222233333333333333344444+85
#  8 | 000000000000000011111111111122222333444444555669
#  9 | 01

stem(two, 0.5)

#  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

#  1 | 889
#  2 | 222333344
#  2 | 555556666666777777778888888888999999999999
#  3 | 000000000000111111111111222222222222222333333333333344444444444444
#  3 | 55555555555555566666666666666667777777777777777888888888888888899999+1
#  4 | 00000000000000011111111111122222222222333333333334444444444444
#  4 | 55555555555555555555666666666666666666667777777777777777777788888888+25
#  5 | 00000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111222222222222+51
#  5 | 555555555555555556666666666667777777777788888888999999
#  6 | 000001111222223344
#  6 | 556
```

An alternative approach:

```
xone <- rasterToPoints(raster1, function(x)x==1)
xtwo <- rasterToPoints(raster2, function(x)x==1)

hist(xone[,2], xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,.3),col="red",freq=F,main="",xlab="Latitude")
hist(xtwo[,2],freq=F,col="green",add=T)
```